# docker-compose builds an old version of the app

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After watching some tutorials I tried to `dockerize` a `node.js` app via `docker-compose`, but encountered a problem. 
Running the command `sudo docker-compose up` app seemed to build the app and run it. Indeed, it works, but somehow it built an old version of the app totally different from the app which runs locally. 
Assuming that docker builds from `master` branch, I updated the `master` branch, but didn't help.
Then I tried to stop, `sudo docker-compose stop` , delete and `recreate`, but same result.

I also had to change `mongo port`  from '27017:27017'  to '27018:27017', since it was throwing an error for having same `ports` running at the same time.  
Here is the error for `ports`

```
ERROR: for a9df50cd75ad_a9df50cd75ad_a9df50cd75ad_mongo  Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mongo (1cc6f9047ccafde83776075e8fa22f86a75eb653bf9f4f0953bd76ee8120a99d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:27017: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for mongo  Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mongo (1cc6f9047ccafde83776075e8fa22f86a75eb653bf9f4f0953bd76ee8120a99d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:27017: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

expose 8000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
  app: 
    container_name: docker-commerce
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports: 
    - '8000:8000'
    links: 
    - mongo 
  mongo: 
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports: 
      - '27018:27017'
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try `docker-compoae build -no-cache` and then `docker-compose up`

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, thanks for the answer. I tried the commands you said, but still have the same result.

Comment: What's the difference between the app that runs locally and under Docker Compose? Is it the data or the UI? It's curious that you needed to revise the exposed port to `27018`. This suggests that you're running another instance of MongoDB locally (or some other server) and this is using port `27017`. There should be no issue running MongoDB on host port `27017` accessing the container on port `27017` otherwise.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin,  I updated my post with error I got have the the same port for mongo. 
When I say different versions of the app, I mean the running container is not the version of project, when I run it locally. It is an old version, that I had a month ago.

Answer (score 3):

Everytime you update the app just run the below to update the container;

**docker-compose up -d --build**

This will build the new image if there are changes in the code files and update the container and keep running it in the background as detached.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Laique Sario, thanks for you answer. Unfortunately this didn't help either. Don't know what is the problem.

Comment: It seems it's not updating container because it gives same error as port is already in used. Try running **docker-compose down** and then run same command to build.